# Ejecutar método cada cierto tiempo

Tags: c#, consola

Estoy desarrollando un un juego de tipo poo o my talking tom. Valga la redundancia es para cuidar un pet y quería saber si hay un método para crear un tiempo, es decir, quiero que al cabo de un tiempo haga algo ya sea que cada cierto tiempo le baje el hambre o el animo.

Como puedo programar que una aplicación se ejecuta según un tiempo programado en C#?

Comment: Una posibilidad: [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la clase [`Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) que se ejecuta según el intervalo de tiempo especificado en el constructor:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds); // se ejecutara cada 10 minutos
timer.Elapsed += async ( sender, e ) => {
   Console.log("El gato tiene hambre!");
};
timer.Start(); // indicamos que unicie
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa [`Thred.Sleep(milisegundos)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netcore-3.1) para suspender el hilo actual por el número de milisegundos indicado. Por ejemplo:

```
//Tu código
Thread.Sleep(5000); //5 segundos
Console.WriteLine("este mensaje aparecerá después de 5 segundos");
```

Answer (score 0):

si tu proyecto se ejecuta en .net 6

la mejor opción es ocupar la clase [PeriodicTimer.](https://www.ilkayilknur.com/a-new-modern-timer-api-in-dotnet-6-periodictimer)
la cual facilita y simplifica mucho.

El ejemplo que corre en MAUI para una app android. y se usa la plantilla por defecto

```
private async Task TimerAndroidAsync() 
{
    var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    CounterBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);

    while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
    {
        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        await DisplayAlert("Test", "el valor es true y se ejecuta cada 5 segundos", "Ok");
        count++;
        if (count >= 4)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
            await DisplayAlert("Test", "Saliste del timer", "Ok");
            CounterBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        }   
    }
}
```

El metodo se ejecuta en el botón.

```
private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    await TimerAndroidAsync();
}
```

El ejemplo está en el siguiente enlace https://github.com/Turel1993/TimerApp